# Removing text within brackets after a click function

Tags: jquery, html

I have the Jquery that i have put inside the `<head>`:

```
$('#change_text').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
});
```

Which removes everything within the `[]` brackets.

And the html:

```
<div id="change_text">Hello [username]</div>
```

And that all works fine on removing `[username]`

---

But I also have the Jquery:

```
$('#change_text').click(function(){
    $(this).html("Hey [username2]")
});
```

But when you **click** it doesn't remove the `[username2]`

Here is a [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcESA/)

Comment: The reason is the text function is not continuously run. It is only a one time change, so when you click, it will not run the text.replace call again. What are your really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Jason for it to tun the `text.replace` call after you have clicked

Comment: I will not be called automatically. You would have to make the call yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.text()` does not track your element. Try wrapping it into function and call it anytime you change html.

```
function changetext(){
    $('#change_text').text(function(_, text) {
        return text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
    });
}
$('#change_text').click(function(){
    $(this).html("Hey [username2]");
    changetext();
});
changetext();
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8EX6e/)

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeText(text){
    return text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
}

$('#change_text').text(function(_, text) {
        return text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
    });

$('#change_text').click(function(){
    $(this).html(changeText("Hey [username2]"))
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcESA/1/)